# Is there a possibility to check if an SVN update would result in a conflict?

Tags: svn

Before I do an `svn up`, I'd like to see in what that operation would result. Specifically, I would want to know in advance if one of my files would go into a conflicted state, but also, which files have changed. So, is there a possibility to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, but not with `svn up`. You can use this command:

```
svn merge -–dry-run -r BASE:HEAD
```

Comment: svn: Merge source required. Damnit, maybe my version is too old.